# Installing Ubuntu along side windows

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-7

how can I install ubuntu along side my windows 7 os without wubi? I am trying to put ubuntu on its own partition. I have already shrunk my c drive and have a u drive of 140 gb for ubuntu.

Comment: 1 of many: http://askubuntu.com/questions/214413/how-to-install-windows-os-along-side-of-ubuntu-12-04?rq=1 Have your pick at the "related" section at the right hand side of your screen.

Answer (score 1):

download this windows installer from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer?distro=wubi&release=&bits= install it on your windows 7 restart your system it will ask for os selection windows 7 or ubuntu click ubuntu....enjoy linux..

Comment: I completely agree with this answer. Just to add a comment, please backup windows data before doing this installer. I did this with an old version. but this will change the boot loader. If you ever need to remove ubuntu, you wont be able to boot into windows. Download EASYBCD to fix the boot manager. http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/ Hope this helps.